# How to prove a certain integral is convergent, but not absolutely convergent?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Been struggling with this problem for quite some time now and can't seem to be able to find the solution by myself.

The said integral is

$$
\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \sin(x\ln^{1/3}(x))\ \mathrm{d}x
$$

I managed to proof it's only convergent using Abel - Dirichlet's test but that's pretty much everything. Cannot prove it's not absolutely convergent. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: The trick here is to use $|\sin y|\ge \sin^2 y=(1-\cos 2y)/2.$ The integral of the second summand is finite for the same reason as the original integral, the first summand makes the integral of the absolute value infinite.

Comment: Okay tell me if I got the idea right.
We're gonna prove that (1-cos2y)/2 diverges, and thus that |siny| diverges, and thus that the original integral is not absolutely convergent.
But how can we prove that  (1-cos2y)/2 diverges?

Comment: I said that, already: because the integral over $\cos2y$ (where $y$ is your function $x\ln^{1/3}(x)$) converges using that very same test, but the integral over the positive constant $1/2$ is certainly infinite when integrating from $0$ to $\infty.$